# How can I interface python with the serial output from an Arduino Uno on a Mac?

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to create a musical instrument with my Arduino and mac combined. So far, I have this programmed in to my Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  pinMode(6, INPUT);
  pinMode(7, INPUT);
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  pinMode(9, INPUT);
  pinMode(10, INPUT);
  pinMode(11, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

  for (int var = 2; var <= 11; var++) {
     if (digitalRead(var) == HIGH) {
       Serial.println(var);
     }
  }
  delay(1);
}
```

It basically returns a number when a connection is made based on which pin made the connection. I really want to be able to read this data in to python so I can play sounds et cetera. Keep in mind I have a mac. I have tried to download pyserial to no avail.I have python 3.4.3(this can be changed)

Comment: Did you use pip to try to install pyserial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interfacing is pretty simple if you have successfully installed [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/#). The [Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/python) gives you examples how to read and write data to arduino via pyserial.

**Read**

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial', 9600)
>>> while True:
...     print ser.readline()
'1 Hello world!\r\n'
'2 Hello world!\r\n'
'3 Hello world!\r\n'
```

**Write**

```
>>> import serial # if you have not already done so
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial', 9600)
>>> ser.write('5')
```

*For Python 3.x*

```
>>> ser.write(b'5') # prefix b is required for Python 3.x, optional for Python 2.x
```